# Does code in my class prevent immutability?

Tags: java, immutability

I wrote classes and I've been told they aren't immutable, but should be.

```
public class Author {
 private String name;
 private String publisher;
 public Author(String name, String publisher) {
  this.name = name;
  this.publisher = publisher;
 }
 public String getName() { return name; }
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
 public String getPublisher() { return publisher; }
 public void setPublisher(String publisher) { this.publisher = publisher; }
}
```

And my second class.

```
public final class Book {

 private final String title;
 private final Author author;
 private final Date datePublished;

 public Book(String title, Author author, Date datePublished) { 
   this.title = title;
   this.author = author;
   this.datePublished = datePublished;
 }

 public String getTitle() { return title; }
 public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
 public Author getAuthor() { return author; }
 public Date getDatePublished() { return datePublished; }
}
```

I believe the set methods prevent immutability, but am I missing something else? Can the get methods break immutability too? If so does that mean the     this.title etc. setter also prevent it?

Comment: If it is supposed to be immutable, then why have `setters` ?  It sends the wrong messages doesn't it.

Comment: Hi, I need to have setters for later functionality. I just need to understand what holds my classes back from being immutable. So far I've deduced the book author being public and the setter methods. I'm just not sure whether the getter for author does too.

Comment: Immutable = you can't change it.  Setters = you can change it.

Comment: If you remove the setters, you can still edit a Book by creating a new one.

Comment: @NomadMaker A bookshop may have many books that are exactly the same but none of them can be changed - hence Immutable.  Maybe you are thinking about Singletom?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No. You can have a constructor that takes a Book object to create a clone of the original. This is called a copy-constructor.

Comment: @NomadMaker - How is a Copy the same as being mutable?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it doesnt make anything mutable. It's a  convenience if you need multiples of an object. Like 7 copies of "War and Peace" in a bookstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Book` class is not immutable because of this method:

```
 public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
```

It also won't compile because the assignment is not allowed.  You can't assign to a `final` field in a method.

The `Author` class is not immutable either.  It has setters and mutable (not `final`) fields, and is not a `final` class.

---

> Can the get methods break immutability too?

Well ... it depends what they do.  For example, a getter that returned reference to a (private) array field makes it possible for a caller to mutate the (effective) state of the object.  And a "getter" could update a cache or an access counter, which could be considered as a mutation.

In your case though, No.  (IMO)

---

> Doesn't the `getAuthor()` break immutability? I can't understand why it wouldn't now since `Author` is public.

Actually, mutability is a rather complicated property in Java, and you can get different "answers" depending on what you actually mean by immutable.

For example, you ask if the fact that `Author` is mutable would also make a `Book` mutable too.

- If you look at it from a modelling perspective, the answer is probably no.  Correcting the spelling of an author's name doesn't change the books that they wrote.  The `Author` is not *part of* the `Book`.  (Probably).
- But if you were to look at it from the perspective of (say) serializing a `Book`, and the `Author` is included in the serialization, then changing the `Author` alters the serialized form.

In this case, I would be inclined to say it doesn't make `Book` mutable.  But in other cases, the answer could be different.

Comment: Hi, ok thank you. Doesn't the getAuthor() break immutability? I can't understand why it wouldn't now sine Author is public

Comment: Since Author is mutable, then handing out a reference to the Book's Author means that anyone can change it: `book.getAuthor().setName("me")`.  To protect against that, hand out a copy of the Author.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer. I think you've cleared up a topic that was really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

'immutability' means various things, it's a nebulously defined term. Most usually it means 'its state cannot be directly changed'.

`getAuthor()` doesn't change any state - it just lets you observe it. Yeah, it's public, but that's not what 'immutable' means. immutable, as in 'not capable of being mutated', as in, 'unchanging'.

Strings in java are unchanging. Given:

```
String x = "Hello";
someMethod(x);
```

there is nothing you can possibly write in `someMethod` that would cause `x` to be anything else. For example, `x.toLowerCase()` won't do it: That does not CHANGE the object x refers to - that makes a *new* object.

On the other hand, given:

```
Book b = new Book("Gulliver's Travels");
someMethod(b);
System.out.println(b.getTitle());
```

Could feasibly print 'Hitchhiker's guide' if someMethod is:

```
public void someMethod(Book b) {
    b.setTitle("Hitchhiker's guide");
}
```

That is why your book is mutable.

mutability grows a little nebulous when state is elsewhere. For example, `java.io.File` has only final fields, no setters, and no method changes any of its internal state (the fields it has). However, you can still 'modify its state and then observe this modification': `someFileObj.delete();` very much does change something and that change is quite observable. Whether j.i.File is immutable depends on who you ask (it depends on how you care to define immutable). You can also get into some crazy shenanigans with static IdentityHashMaps but lets not go too far with it - for most cases immutability boils down to something very very simple:

- Make all fields `final`.

Voila. That's it. You'll find that it's not even possible to write that set method at all. set methods are fundamentally incompatible with the notation of immutability - at best, you can have methods that make new modified clones, just like `"Hello".toLowerCase()` isn't a setter - it makes a new string object, by cloning this one, but lowercasing each character in it. These methods are by convention called 'with' methods:

```
public class Book {
    private final String title, author;

    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getAuthor() { return author; }

    public Book withAuthor(String newAuthor) {
        return new Book(this.title, newAuthor);
    }
}
```

This method (`withAuthor`) does NOT change your book. It makes a new book, with the same title as this book, but with the stated author.

NB: Another common way to get into the nebulousness of the term is if you have a final field that is of a mutable type. Imagine:

```
public class Book {
    // books can actually have multiple authors...
    private List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getAuthors() { return authors; }
}
```

is this class immutable? For most intents and purposes **it is not immutable**:

```
book.getAuthors().add("Reinier Zwitserloot");
```

the fix would be to ensure that that list is also immutable. `List.of` makes immutable lists, or you can make it effectively immutable by wrapping it: `list = Collections.unmodifiableList(someArrayList);` would get the job done.

This is quite complex material for first-steps java. Let's stick with: Be aware that if a field type can contain mutable things, then there's not much you can do - having no setter and having a final field doesn't help anymore. Strings, and all primitives - all immutable, though. Fortunately.